# Read and Update Textbox value in Gridview on Row Button Click Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview

there is a `Gridview` with `textbox` and `button` in each row. I am getting the value of `textbox` and another column. After that I am creating `SHA512` of both values then again it's need to update to the same `password` textbox on button clicked for that corresponding row. How should I do this?

Below is the `JQuery` event I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {

                $("[id*=grduserdetail]").find("[id*=btnpass]").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    //Reference the GridView Row.
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var unm = row.find('.userid').text();
                    var pwd = row.find($('[id*=txtpass]')).val();
                    var pwdLength = false;
                    if (pwd.length >= 6)
                        pwdLength = true;

                    var hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(pwd);
                    var hasLowerCase = /[a-z]/.test(pwd);
                    var hasNumbers = /\d/.test(pwd);
                    var hasNonalphas = /[@#&!$%^&*()]/.test(pwd);

                    if (!((hasUpperCase + hasLowerCase + hasNumbers + hasNonalphas + pwdLength) > 4)) {
                        alert('Password must be 6 charaters long and contain one Upper case one lower case one digit and one special character !');
                        return false;
                    } else {

                        //$(this).prev()[0].value = SHA512(unm.text() + pwd.val());
                        pwd.value = SHA512(unm + pwd);
                        //document.getElementById("shhidden").value = SHA512(unm + pwd);
                        return true;
                    }

                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "then again it's need to update to the same password textbox"

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider : For example, If there is 5 rows in `Gridview`. Each row has `textbox` and `button`. If I click on `button` from 1 row index then that `textbox` should get update. If I click on 2 row index `button` then that `textbox` should get update vice versa.

Comment: textbox should get updated with what? encrypted value?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider: Yes! with encrypted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `SHA512(unm + pwd)`would be giving you the encrypted value as you need . to set password textbox's text as encrypted value (based on your comment) try:

```
var encryptedVal = SHA512(unm + pwd)
row.find($('[id*=txtpass]')).val(encryptedVal)
```